# do inherited functions work on base class elements or derived class elements in c++?

Tags: c++

Suppose i have two classes such that :

```
class base
    {
         int hello;
         public:
         base
         {
             hello=5;
         }
         void show()
         {
             cout<<hello;
         }
    };

class derived:public hello
    {
         int hello;
         public:
         derived()
         {
             hello=2;
         }
             show();
    };
```

now i want to know will it display 2 or 5 ? and if so then why and how do i make it go the other way round ?

Comment: Did you try to compile and run the code?

Comment: not at pc atm , so cant compile , had to type this all on a mobile screen

Comment: If you are asking technical questions, you should be sitting in front of a computer that can compile the code that forms part of the question, and not use a mobile phone.

Answer (score 2):

No, because you have two distinct and separate variables `hello`. The one in the `derived` class sort of "overrides" the one in the `base` class.

If you want it to work, you need to have only one variable.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that, public inheritance models the *is-a* relationship. The derived class is a base class. The constructor of the derived class will implicitly call the constructor of the base class.